# whats wrong with this python script

Tags: function, numpy

I have a simple script which returns a lot of errors:

```
import numpy as np
def test(array):
    ncol=np.shape(array)[1]
    return ncol
```

which is supposed to return the number of columns of array. What is wrong with it?

array is numpy array. Here is the output:

`ncol=np.shape(array)[1]
  Display all 195 possibilities? (y or n)
  ArithmeticError(            continue
  AssertionError(             copyright(
  AttributeError(             credits(
  BaseException(              def
  BlockingIOError(            del`

Comment: What errors does it return? What is the value of `array`?

Comment: I have added errors. array is a numpy array

Comment: How do you use the script? What is the explicit command that you issue to obtain the errors above?

Comment: I copy and past the code in a python shell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `try.. catch` around `ncol=np.shape(array)[1]` because it fails when the array is a 1d dimension:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.normal(size=10)
arr1 = np.random.normal(size=(10,5))

def test(array):
    try:
        ncol=np.shape(array)[1]
        return ncol
    except Exception as e:
        print("no columns in array")
        return None

print(test(arr))
# output:  
# no columns in array
# None

print(test(arr1))
# output: 
# 5
```